# How do i retrieve an Object stored in a ist in the form of KeyValuePair in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, keyvaluepair

I have the following `List` with `KeyValuePair` as the data.

```
using SerialPort as PORT
List<KeyValuePair<string, PORT>> myPortList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, PORT>>();
```

I have added elements to the `list` in the following manner

```
PORT sp1 = new PORT("COM1", 9200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
PORT sp2 = new PORT("COM4", 9200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
myPortList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,PORT>("COM1",sp1));
myPortList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,PORT>("COM4",sp2));
```

How do i get the SerialPort object stored in the list using the key?

**Eg:**

 Need to retrieve `value`  **sp2** by using the `key` **"COM4"**  from the `list` **myPortList** ?

Comment: Why are you using `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` when you could use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
myPortList.Fist(kp => kp.Key.Equals("COM4"));
```

If you can do, use `Dictionary` instead, itt will be more easy to get elements from it.

Exemple for `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, PORT> myPortDict = new Dictionary<string, PORT>();

PORT sp2 = new PORT("COM4", 9200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
myPortDict.Add("COM4",sp1);

//then to retrive:

dc.TryGetValue("COM4", out PORT myPort);

//then use myPort
```

Comment: Can You please help me in using Dictionary instead of List?

Comment: Copy-Paste the code I've written, it will work. Where you define your list, change it to my Dictionary's declaration and change the occurences of list variable to dictionary's variable.

Comment: worked well for me, I really appreciate your support and help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq for this:

```
myPortList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "COM4").Value
```

It may be easier to use a Dictionary instead of a List of `KeyValuePair` items, then you can access the items in a more direct manner.

Comment: Can You please help me in using Dictionary instead of List?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ. Try this, may be help you.

```
var result = myPortList.Find(x => x.Key == "COM4");
var value = result.Value;
```